# How to exclude file/folder from visual studio project?

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, csproj

I can't find any option or command to make a file or folder to be excluded from my visual studio project. (csproj, jsproj ... )

There is the option to include files and folders in the Solution Explorer -> Show All Files -> *left mouse click on target* -> Include In Project.

but there is no option for **exclude**...

I'm using VS 2015.

I noticed that the option for exclude was available in VS 2008 and 2010. by this doc:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebzhwsk(v=vs.100).aspx

any solution?

thanks

**EDIT:**

The problem is only in ***jsproj*** type of project (Apache Cordova project for example). excuding in *csproj* is working great.

Answer (score 6):

Visual Studio 2019:

Example: remove relative folder node_modules

add this to csproj file

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Remove="ClientApp\node_modules\**" />
  <Content Remove="ClientApp\node_modules\**" />
  <EmbeddedResource Remove="ClientApp\node_modules\**" />
  <None Remove="ClientApp\node_modules\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 5):

[image]

I have the German version and it shows "exclude from project", when right-clicking on the Item/File/Directory

I also can use *"Project > Exclude selected File from Project"*.
It could look like your Installation is broken. Maybe update/reinstall VS to solve the problem...

---

btw.: This is VS2015...

---

**EDIT №1:** [This thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/2062212.aspx?Where%20is%20the%20Exclude%20From%20Project%20feature%20in%20VS2015%20Community%20Edition%20) does also complain about the context menu option not showing up, but I could not find the answer.

---

**EDIT №2:** You could edit your `.csproj`-file using a text editor to manually include or exclude different files, but it is always a bit ponderous to close the project, edit the file and reopen the project....

The appropriate tag is named `<ItemGroup>` and should look like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="css\foundation.css" />
  <Content Include="css\foundation.min.css" />
  <Content Include="css\main.css" />
  <Content Include="img\my_image.png" />
 ...
</ItemGroup>
```

Simply change the first attribute from `Include` to `Exclude`. If this does not work, try to uncomment the specific files/directories:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <!--
  <Content Include="file\to_be.ignored" />
  -->
 ...
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: hey thanks to you I noticed that in a **csproj**  type of project this option is available! my project is **jsproj type (Apache Cordova project)** . in this project there is no exclude option... only include. In adiition there is no information on this in the jsproj xml too....

Comment: @Refacror-Man: I do not often use jsproj but I will dig into this... I will edit my answer as soon as I found something...

Comment: @Refacror-Man: the *jsproj*-file is just like a normal *csproj*-file and has the same structure. I also edited my answer....

Comment: there is no information in the jsproj xml about the files and folders (no Content tags with exclude or include attributes).

Comment: when I am trying to add manualy to the xml somthig like that: 

 `<ItemGroup>
  <Content Exclude="Project_Readme.html" />
 </ItemGroup>`

I saved the xml, then reloaded the project and got an error dialog.
![ERROR image](http://s15.postimg.org/v5npwszqz/error.png).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91421/discussion-between-unknown6656-and-refacror-man).

Answer (score 0):

**VS Version: 1.51.1**

Using settings.json file in the .vscode directory you could add a "files.exclude" property. This worked immediately for me.

```
 "files.exclude": {
    "dist/": true,
    "node_modules/": true,
    ".angular/": true
  },
```